# AngularJS: ui-grid: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHeaders' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, grid

I am running into this error, not sure why. Before it was saying that 'getHeaders' was not a function. Here's the snippets of my code.

```
'use strict';

var first = angular.module('App');
first.controller('NewGridCtrl',  ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$modal', '$interval', '$location', 'uiGridConstants', '$filter', '$rootScope', 'GridService',
function($scope, $http, $timeout, $modal, $interval, $location, uiGridConstants, KG, $filter, $rootScope, GridService) {
$( "div[id^='nvtooltip']" ).css( "display" , "none");

var id, af;
$scope.pageNumber=0;
$scope.orderByColumn=null;

$scope.gridOptions = {
    ....
};

GridService.getHeaders().then(
    function(result){
        $scope.headers = result;
        return true;
    },
    function(error){
        console.error(error);
        return false;
    }
);

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    $scope.headers
];

}]);
```

And then my service:

```
first.factory('GridService', function($q, $http){
return{
    getHeaders: function(){
        return fetchHeaders();
    }
}

function fetchHeaders(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('v1/headers/').success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.reject(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
});
```

Did I miss something - anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one too many parameters in your controller function.

I lined up the injected services to the function params here and you can see the controller function is expecting an object for the KG parameter, but based on the name alignment, it looks like you forgot to specify KG to be injected, so all of the injected objects after that one get shifted back leaving GridService undefined.

```
first.controller('NewGridCtrl',  
       ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$modal', '$interval', '$location', 'uiGridConstants',       '$filter', '$rootScope', 'GridService',
function($scope,   $http,   $timeout,   $modal,   $interval,   $location,   uiGridConstants,   KG,   $filter,   $rootScope,   GridService) {
...}]);
```